# How to change status bar color to match app in Lollipop? [Android]

Tags: android, colors, status, android-5.0-lollipop

In the new lollipop update I noticed that with the native Google apps the color of the status bar changes to match the action bar on the app you're running. I see it's on the Twitter app also so I'm guessing it's not exclusively Google who can do it.

Does anyone know how to do this if it is possible?

Answer (score 224, accepted):

To change status bar color use [setStatusBarColor(int color)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setStatusBarColor(int)).
According the javadoc, we also need set some flags on the window.

Working snippet of code:

```
Window window = activity.getWindow();
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, R.color.example_color));
```

Keep in mind [according Material Design guidelines](http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-ui-color-application) status bar color and action bar color should be different:

- *ActionBar* should use **primary 500 color**
- *StatusBar* should use **primary 700 color**

Look at the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Is this supposed to work without using Material theme?

Comment: Note that the effect may not show up in the emulator. For example, [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MaterialDesign/StatusBarColor) tints the status bar on a Nexus 9 but not on an Android 5.0 emulator.

Comment: @CommonsWare it works for me both: device and emulator(genymotion).

Comment: @mate: I was referring to the Android SDK emulator. Good to know that it is working on Genymotion.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Does this works on those devices that have android version under Kitkat ?

Comment: @Azad No, it dosen't. To use above snippet of code you have to ensure that your device running on API 21 or higher.

Comment: About changing statusBar color;  is it matter difference between pre-lollipop or lollipop devices? If it is matter; how can I change my statusBar color on api level below lollipop?

Comment: What does it mean "700" vs "500" ? Isn't see 700 as the higher number, make it also have more color, thus making it closer to white ?

Comment: I'm working on a relatively simple project and I must say that I just used `getWindow().setStatusBarColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.example_color));` and it worked perfectly. Not sure about the context in which the flags are strictly necessary.

Comment: @androiddeveloper // the meaning of 500 and 700 colors in android:  http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/44453

Comment: @Youngjae This is weird. so what's the math that's needed for this? Suppose you have #550000" , this is probably 500 (base), but how will you compute 600 and 400 ? do you convert the "55" it to decimal, and for 400 you add 15% and for 600 you subtract 10% (and you convert back to hexadecimal) ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper // agree. I have no idea.

Comment: Not working in my case. Gives exception : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.view.Window.setStatusBarColor

Comment: @WISHY you propably didn't run the code on device with Lollipop.

Comment: I want to show the color in pre lollipop devices also. How can it be done?

Comment: Are the flags needed for Lollipop and above? I've just tried what @joaquin said and it's working fine as far as I only want to tint it on Lollipop and above.

Comment: @WISHY You can't change the Status Bar Color on pre-Lollipop devices.

Comment: Having a color X for the action bar , what is the formula to get the best color for the status bar ? How can one convert from color 500 to color 700 ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper Read this one http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/37520/how-does-one-generate-a-palette-similar-to-the-ones-in-googles-material-design

Comment: @mklimek None of them found out the formula. At best, they show other places with built in palettes colors...

Comment: Works on genymotion emulator running Google Nexus 5 API 21.

Comment: @WISHY The status bar is a system window owned by the operating system. On pre-5.0 Android devices, applications do not have permission to alter its color, so this is not something that the AppCompat library can support for older platform versions. The best AppCompat can do is provide support for coloring the ActionBar and other common UI widgets within the application.

Comment: @mklimek HI, I want to set status bar color like in Google Maps App. Map should display behind status bar, i tried this library "com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint" but didn't worked for me. with your code status bar color is setting with RGB value only but not with ARGB value. I want to set tinted background with ARGB value. Please help me!

Comment: its very useful. be careful its works on api-21 and later.

Answer (score 48):

Just add this in you styles.xml.
The colorPrimary is for the action bar and the colorPrimaryDark is for the status bar.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
</style>
```

This picture from developer android explains more about color pallete. You can read more on this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html#ColorPalette).

[image]

Comment: Android Studio creates the following entries for each project: `<color name="colorPrimary">#somecolor</color>` and `<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#somecolor</color>`. They can be changed to achieve the desired effect.

Answer (score 41):

Another way to set the status bar color is through the **style.xml**.

To do that, create a **style.xml** file under **res/values-v21** folder with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
        <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/blue_dark</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**Edit:** as pointed out in comments, when using AppCompat the code is different. In file **res/values/style.xml** use instead:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">   
    <!-- Set AppCompat’s color theming attrs -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_awesome_red</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/my_awesome_darker_red</item>
    <!-- Other attributes -->
</style>
```

Comment: Did that. But did not work. But then I use AppCompat instead of Material.

Comment: @Martin For appcompat, use colorPrimaryDark without the android prefix.

Comment: not working for appcompat as well (tested on Level 18)

Comment: The status bar color will only work on devices with OS API Level 21 and above. Also, in your manifest make sure you are not overriding this style on individual activities.

Comment: for inappbrowser how to change searchbar color same as to app color

Answer (score 23):

To set the status bar color, create a style.xml file under res/values-v21 folder with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/blue</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: it says cannot resolve symbol windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds

Answer (score 4):

Also if you want different `status-bar` color for different activity ([fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41796558/1462770)) you can do it with following steps (work on API 21 and above):

First create `values21/style.xml` and put following code:

```
 <style name="AIO" parent="AIOBase">
            <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
            <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    </style>
```

Then define White|Dark themes in your `values/style.xml` like following:

```
 <style name="AIOBase" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_accent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/color_primary_dark
        </item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/gray_darkest</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/default_bg</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/default_bg</item>
    </style>


    <style name="AIO" parent="AIOBase" />

    <style name="AIO.Dark" parent="AIOBase">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">#171717
        </item>
    </style>

    <style name="AIO.White" parent="AIOBase">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">#bdbdbd
        </item>
    </style>
```

Also don't forget to apply themes in your `manifest.xml`.

Answer (score 4):

Add this line in style of v21 if you use two style.

```
  <item name="android:statusBarColor">#43434f</item>
```

Comment: This doesn't work without setting flag `android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds`

Answer (score 2):

In android pre Lollipop devices you can do it from **SystemBarTintManager**
If you are using android studio just add Systembartint lib in your gradle file.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.3'
    ...
}
```

Then in your activity

```
// create manager instance after the content view is set
SystemBarTintManager mTintManager = new SystemBarTintManager(this);
// enable status bar tint
mTintManager.setStatusBarTintEnabled(true);
mTintManager.setTintColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
```