# How to change the color of status Bar in Android

Tags: android

I am working on an android qt app. I want to change the color of android status bar to be same as that of my application background color. Currently whatever be the color of my application the status bar remains black.Is there any way by which i can make the color of status bar same as my application.I am not Using Java In my application.I want to do this by making changes only to the androidManifest.xml file. Is this possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the status bar color in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

To change status bar color use [setStatusBarColor(int color)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setStatusBarColor(int)). According javadoc, we also need set some flags on Window.

Working snippet of code:

```
Window window = activity.getWindow();
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
window.setStatusBarColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.example_color));
```

Keep in mind, according Material Design guidelines, status bar color and action bar color should be different:

ActionBar should use primary 500 color
StatusBar should use primary 700 color.

Resource:([How to change status bar color to match app in Lollipop? [Android]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093287/how-to-change-status-bar-color-to-match-app-in-lollipop-android))

Comment: I am not using java classes in my app

Comment: This solution left me with BLACK ACTIVITIES in android devices with API < 21. Beware.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add this in your code:
`this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a test project that does that. The important code snippet is:

```
QtAndroid::runOnAndroidThread([=]() {
        QAndroidJniObject window = QtAndroid::androidActivity().callObjectMethod("getWindow", "()Landroid/view/Window;");
        window.callMethod<void>("addFlags", "(I)V", FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.callMethod<void>("clearFlags", "(I)V", FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.callMethod<void>("setStatusBarColor", "(I)V", color.rgba());
});
```

See bug report: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-51196