# Strange custom Toolbar on pre-lollipop devices

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-toolbar

I've issues with the appcompat toolbar on < 5.0 devices.
I was expecting this (Working result on Xperia and Nexus devices with lollipop):

[image: Expecting result]

Unfortunately I do get this on < 5.0 devices; black text and a weird looking statusbar hovering over the toolbar:

[image: AppBar on a 4.4 device]

This is my toolbar design:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:elevation="4dp">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And MainActivity design:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:clickable="true">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar">
        </include>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:background="#33b5e5"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp" />

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"

        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My styles-v21.xml:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Defining code inside MainActivity's onCreate:

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView);
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
Drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.DrawerLayout);
Drawer.setStatusBarBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ColorPrimaryDark));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I finally managed to get rid of this weird issue. I've changed the style.xml for v-19 to this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

Which just makes the statusbar transparent on kitkat devices. And changed nothing in the style-v21.xml and the original styles.xml file.

Then changed the toolbar to add `app:theme` and `app:popupTheme` which is set to display white text theme. And a `android:paddingTop` to change the padding which is needed to be set on kitkat devices.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/tool_bar_top_padding">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

In the default dimens.xml:

```
<dimen name="tool_bar_top_padding">0dp</dimen>
```

dimens-v19.xml:

```
<dimen name="tool_bar_top_padding">20dp</dimen>
```

dimens-v21.xml:

```
<dimen name="tool_bar_top_padding">0dp</dimen>
```

And last but not least removed the `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from the DrawerLayout in the main_activity.xml design

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about reason of this error. But I think a work around can be done if you set **Statusbar background color in Lollipop** from API introduced recently

The API is `setStatusBarColor(int color)` and you are required to set some meaningful flags to `WindowManager` along with it :

Sample found from [this descriptive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27093330/1994950) :

```
Window window = activity.getWindow();
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
window.setStatusBarColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.ColorPrimary)); 
// to set ColorPrimary as status bar background color
```

This will remove the gray background shown in Samsung devices of lollipop

Comment: The statusbar background do not change with above code ?