# How can I change statusbar color without a toolbar?

Tags: android, toolbar, statusbar

I'm trying to make the status bar color #a1a1a1 (white_dark) but it's just black when i run it.

This is my Style v21 file:

```
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="AppTheme">
         <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
         <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/white_dark</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: try setting this `<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/your_color</item>`

Comment: Please look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093287/how-to-change-status-bar-color-to-match-app-in-lollipop-android

Comment: Hi everyone, this doesn't work as i have disabled my toolbar...

Answer (score 0):

you can try this [lib](https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint)

But my personal suggestion is, switch to `AppCompat`because its very easy to change `StatusBar` color in it.

Primary Dark color is used for `StatusBar`:

```
<!-- darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/black</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this theme

```
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
        parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
        parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@color/atctionbar_color</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="background">@color/atctionbar_color</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

and create new file in values>colors.xml and add color from there

```
<resources>
    <color name="atctionbar_color">#170053</color>
</resources>
```