# Customize Statusbar - Android

Tags: android, statusbar

I am creating an application with some Activities. I want to change the status bar color and status bar icon colors which should look like the following image.

[image].

Is it possible to change? I am able to change the background color using the following code.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
{
    Window w = getWindow(); // in Activity's onCreate() for instance
    w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
    w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    w.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white_background_text));
}
```

Above code is working fine. Now **I want to change the Wi-Fi icon, network icon, battery and time. Is it possible to do?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the status bar color in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android)

Comment: Seems like this would help http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1245404

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27093330/1168654

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android statusbar icons color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30075827/android-statusbar-icons-color)

Comment: I read all those links. Can anyone please tell me what is the difference between my code and those codes? I want to change the icons. Status bar background already working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

From another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33894882/940720)

> Yes it's possible to change it to gray (no custom colors) but this only works from API 23 and above you only need to add this in your values-v23/styles.xml
>
> `<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>`