# How to set and reset status bar color to original based on some condition in android

Tags: android, statusbar

I want to change the color of status bar,and did the same as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093287/how-to-change-status-bar-color-to-match-app-in-lollipop-android) . I have the following doubts.
1) but i want to reset status bar color to original based on some condition, how will i do that.
I have tried like this.

```
public class StoreDisableHelper {

    public static void changeStatusBarColor(boolean status,Activity activity){
        Window window = activity.getWindow();
        if(status){


// clear FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS flag:
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);

// add FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS flag to the window
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);

// finally change the color
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                window.setStatusBarColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.theme_red));
            }

        }
        else{
            window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        }

    }
}
```

when the condition is false, i am resetting

Comment: Can you please show what you have tried yet? Please take a look at our [how to ask guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: see, on some condition like lets say on monday and tuesday i want to change the color of status bar to red, and on wednesday i want to reset to how it was previously without red color. How will i do that? I did it by re-setting the flag, but in devices below lollipop, its affecting the Title bar .

Comment: By "show what you have tried" I meant to provide some code samples. This will help experts from the field point you to errors if any. Right now, they will have to guess what you are doing!

Comment: Use AppCompat Library if you want your code to work same on all devices.

Answer (score 2):

This this:

https://gist.github.com/MrThiago/4897424c3c773aec57081325f273311a

private static int defaultStatusBarColor;

```
public static void changeStatusBarColor(Activity context, boolean change, int color){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
    {
        Window window = context.getWindow();
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);

        if(change){
            defaultStatusBarColor = window.getStatusBarColor();
            window.setStatusBarColor(color);
        }
        else{
            // reset
            window.setStatusBarColor(defaultStatusBarColor);
        }
    }
}
```