# How can I set color for statusbar in android

Tags: android, android-styles, android-statusbar

How Can I set color for status bar in android?

I've tried both in styles.xml and in .java file.

If I try following code in .java class

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(Color.DKGRAY));
    }
```

I'm getting as exception called : -ResourceNotFoundException

```
04-01 18:55:21.616: E/AndroidRuntime(2169): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp.cz/com.myapp.casenotez.updateCase}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xff444444
04-01 18:55:21.616: E/AndroidRuntime(2169):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
04-01 18:55:21.616: E/AndroidRuntime(2169):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
04-01 18:55:21.616: E/AndroidRuntime(2169):     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
04-01 18:55:21.616: E/AndroidRuntime(2169):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
04-01 18:55:21.616: E/AndroidRuntime(2169):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-01 18:55:21.616: E/AndroidRuntime(2169):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
04-01 18:55:21.616: E/AndroidRuntime(2169):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
04-01 18:55:21.616: E/AndroidRuntime(2169):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 04-01 18:55:21.616: E/AndroidRuntime(2169):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
 04-01 18:55:21.616: E/AndroidRuntime(2169):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 04-01 18:55:21.616: E/AndroidRuntime(2169): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xff444444
 04-01 18:55:21.616: E/AndroidRuntime(2169):    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1351)
 04-01 18:55:21.616: E/AndroidRuntime(2169):    at android.content.res.Resources.getColor(Resources.java:963)
 04-01 18:55:21.616: E/AndroidRuntime(2169):    at android.content.res.Resources.getColor(Resources.java:936)
 04-01 18:55:21.616: E/AndroidRuntime(2169):    at com.myapp.cz.updateCase.onCreate(updateCase.java:112)
 04-01 18:55:21.616: E/AndroidRuntime(2169):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
 04-01 18:55:21.616: E/AndroidRuntime(2169):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
 04-01 18:55:21.616: E/AndroidRuntime(2169):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
 04-01 18:55:21.616: E/AndroidRuntime(2169):    ... 9 more
```

And I also tried by adding styles in styles.xml:-

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#630</item>
     <item name="android:titleTextStyle">       @style/MyActionBarTitle</item>
</style>
<style name="MyActionBarTitle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/Blue</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/a/27093330/4790490

Comment: I don't think you have to call `getResources().getColor(Color.DKGRAY))` I think you can just pass in `Color.DKGRAY`. The error says it's trying to get  `Resource ID #0xff444444` but that is the hex value for a solid Dark Gray color.

Answer (score 5):

`Color.DKGRAY` is already a properly-formed color int. You can just use

```
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.DKGRAY);
```

You only need to use `Resources.getColor()` if you are resolving a color resource id, like so:

```
<resources>
    <color name="dark_gray">#ff444444</color>
</resources>

getWindow().setBackgroundColor(getResources.getColor(R.color.dark_gray));
```

In this case, `R.color.dark_gray` is not a color int, it is a resource id. That's the difference.

**EDIT**

You can easily set the status bar color in your theme instead. Note that it only takes effect on Lollipop and above. You could use translucent status bar on KitKat. If you do it this way, you don't need any java code to set window flags.

Note that I am assuming you are using the AppCompat library. If you are not, you probably should.

in res/values/styles.xml:

```
<!-- Extend from any AppCompat theme -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- put your theme customizations in here -->
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.TranslucentStatus" />
```

in res/values-19/styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme.TranslucentStatus">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

in res/values-21/styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme.TranslucentStatus">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">#ff444444</item>
</style>
```

Use `AppTheme.TranslucentStatus` on the Activities that should have translucent status bar.

Comment: OKay.. Thank you ..:) And Is it possible to set status bar color in style.xml ? In the above code which I have posted in question..Its changing only the color of texts of actionbar not status bar.?

Answer (score 1):

This method is available in API Level 21,so you may want to check 
what the Target Framework setting is configured as within the project options.

```
    And, you will need to include a check like this to verify
```

this only executes when running on Lollipop (API 21) or higher:

```
                if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
                {
                    Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentStatus);
                    Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.DrawsSystemBarBackgrounds);
                    Window.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Blue);
                }
```

Or you may try this function...

```
public void setStatusBarColor(@ColorRes int statusBarColor) {
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    int color = ContextCompat.getColor(this, statusBarColor);

    Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.setStatusBarColor(color);
  }
}
```

Comment: OKay.. Thank you ..:) And Is it possible to set status bar color in style.xml ? In the above code which I have posted in question..Its changing only the color of texts of actionbar not status bar.?