# Toolbar haven't the full size

Tags: android, toolbar

Hey Guys I want to make a Custom Toolbar. I tried so many things but nothing works.... So I have this in my manifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true">
    <activity android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!--android:theme="@style/HomeActionBar">-->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

And here my activity_home.xml:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.iiiii.iiiii.HomeActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways|scroll" />

    <!-- <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Delete SharedPreferences" /> -->

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

But look! I didn't get the full size of the ActionBar:
[image]

Comment: Change the  android:layout_width="368dp" to android:layout_width="match_parent"

Comment: @FarshidABZ Nothing changed...Again the same problem..

Comment: So add full .xml file here.

Comment: I think your coordinatorLayout or Toolbar's parent has padding attr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You must change the width of ToolBar**

> The code will look like:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.iiiii.iiiii.HomeActivity"
  >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways|scroll" />

    <!-- <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Delete SharedPreferences" /> -->

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Could you please show your full xml file so that we can detect the problem

Comment: remove all padding from CoordinatorLayout. I have update my answer u can check now :)

Comment: How to fill the StatusBar with the same color? With code in xml?

Answer (score 1):

Remove CoordinatorLayout's padding attributes.

Replace your XML with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.iiiii.iiiii.HomeActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways|scroll" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: How to fill the StatusBar with the same color? With code in xml?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093287/how-to-change-status-bar-color-to-match-app-in-lollipop-android   @user7118518

Answer (score 0):

Move paddings to inner layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.iiiii.iiiii.HomeActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways|scroll" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```